# Toggle absolute and relative numbering in VIM by insert/normal mode

Tags: vim

I use the relative line number setting in vim. I would like vim to automatically switch to absolute line numbers when I am in insert mode and back to relative in normal mode. Currently I have tried this code in my vimrc

```
  autocmd InsertEnter * :set number                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  autocmd InsertLeave * :set relativenumber
```

Unfortunately this only gets me part of the way there. This toggles on relative numbers the first time I leave insert mode, but will no longer go back to absolute numbers upon entering insert mode again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, do a

```
set number
```

Then

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :set norelativenumber
autocmd InsertLeave * :set relativenumber
```

Comment: Although this solves the issue of line numbers not being present upon opening vim, it does not solve the problem I am asking about. Once relative line numbers are turned on, absolute never come back, I would like for absolute numbers to return upon re-entering insert mode

Comment: Oh, I understood the reverse. You want *absolute* line numbers in insert mode, then? In this case, just reverse the two sets I posted.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try again, now they are reversed.